# Problem with exports pgf/tikz graphic of geogebra to latex

Tags: geogebra

When I try to export this graphics, I get a drawing with only coordinate axes.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
\begin{axis}[
x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm,
axis lines=middle,
ymajorgrids=true,
xmajorgrids=true,
xmin=-3.9999999999999982,
xmax=3.979999999999998,
ymin=-2.9800000000000013,
ymax=2.9800000000000013,
xtick={-3.0,-2.0,...,3.0},
ytick={-2.0,-1.0,...,2.0},]
\clip(-4.,-2.98) rectangle (3.98,2.98);
\draw[line width=0.8pt,smooth,samples=100,domain=6.920000002293365E-6:0.9999961013223213] plot(\x,{sqrt(((\x)*((\x)-1.0)*((\x)-2.0))/6.0)});
\draw[line width=0.8pt,smooth,samples=100,domain=2.000002653901591:3.979999999999998] plot(\x,{sqrt(((\x)*((\x)-1.0)*((\x)-2.0))/6.0)});
\draw[line width=0.8pt,smooth,samples=100,domain=6.920000002293365E-6:0.9999961013223213] plot(\x,{0-sqrt(((\x)*((\x)-1.0)*((\x)-2.0))/6.0)});
\draw[line width=0.8pt,smooth,samples=100,domain=2.000002653901591:3.979999999999998] plot(\x,{0-sqrt(((\x)*((\x)-1.0)*((\x)-2.0))/6.0)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I always start by removing the usually bad `\clip` instruction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quickest fix is to add `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}` to the preamble.

By default, the coordinates of normal TikZ drawing macros like `\draw` do *not* correspond to axis units, when used inside an `axis` environment. Starting with the compatibility setting of `1.11` though, `pgfplots` changes the default, so coordinates do correspond to axis coordinates, and not those of the underlying `tikzpicture`. (I think this is the cause at least, though I'm not completely certain.)

---

That said, I would personally rather change the code to use the `\addplot` macro of `pgfplots` instead of `\draw plot`, i.e.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45]
\begin{axis}[
axis lines=middle,
ymajorgrids=true,
xmajorgrids=true,
xmin=-3.9999999999999982,
xmax=3.979999999999998,
ymin=-2.9800000000000013,
ymax=2.9800000000000013,
xtick={-3.0,-2.0,...,3.0},
ytick={-2.0,-1.0,...,2.0}
]

\addplot [line width=0.8pt,smooth,samples=100,domain=6.920000002293365E-6:0.9999961013223213] (\x,{sqrt(((\x)*((\x)-1.0)*((\x)-2.0))/6.0)});
\addplot [line width=0.8pt,smooth,samples=100,domain=2.000002653901591:3.979999999999998] (\x,{sqrt(((\x)*((\x)-1.0)*((\x)-2.0))/6.0)});
\addplot [line width=0.8pt,smooth,samples=100,domain=6.920000002293365E-6:0.9999961013223213] (\x,{0-sqrt(((\x)*((\x)-1.0)*((\x)-2.0))/6.0)});
\addplot[line width=0.8pt,smooth,samples=100,domain=2.000002653901591:3.979999999999998] (\x,{0-sqrt(((\x)*((\x)-1.0)*((\x)-2.0))/6.0)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

By the way, `\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}` is a bit redundant, `pgfplots` loads `tikz` which loads `pgf`, so you really only need `\usepackage{pgfplots}`.

Complete example and output:

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
Modified code:

\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45]
\begin{axis}[
axis lines=middle,
ymajorgrids=true,
xmajorgrids=true,
xmin=-3.9999999999999982,
xmax=3.979999999999998,
ymin=-2.9800000000000013,
ymax=2.9800000000000013,
xtick={-3.0,-2.0,...,3.0},
ytick={-2.0,-1.0,...,2.0}
]

\addplot [line width=0.8pt,smooth,samples=100,domain=6.920000002293365E-6:0.9999961013223213] (\x,{sqrt(((\x)*((\x)-1.0)*((\x)-2.0))/6.0)});
\addplot [line width=0.8pt,smooth,samples=100,domain=2.000002653901591:3.979999999999998] (\x,{sqrt(((\x)*((\x)-1.0)*((\x)-2.0))/6.0)});
\addplot [line width=0.8pt,smooth,samples=100,domain=6.920000002293365E-6:0.9999961013223213] (\x,{0-sqrt(((\x)*((\x)-1.0)*((\x)-2.0))/6.0)});
\addplot[line width=0.8pt,smooth,samples=100,domain=2.000002653901591:3.979999999999998] (\x,{0-sqrt(((\x)*((\x)-1.0)*((\x)-2.0))/6.0)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

With \texttt{compat=1.11}:

% in general you want this line in the preamble, I added it here just for the sake
% of the example, to show that the above code works without it
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
\begin{axis}[
x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm,
axis lines=middle,
ymajorgrids=true,
xmajorgrids=true,
xmin=-3.9999999999999982,
xmax=3.979999999999998,
ymin=-2.9800000000000013,
ymax=2.9800000000000013,
xtick={-3.0,-2.0,...,3.0},
ytick={-2.0,-1.0,...,2.0},]
\clip(-4.,-2.98) rectangle (3.98,2.98);
\draw[line width=0.8pt,smooth,samples=100,domain=6.920000002293365E-6:0.9999961013223213] plot(\x,{sqrt(((\x)*((\x)-1.0)*((\x)-2.0))/6.0)});
\draw[line width=0.8pt,smooth,samples=100,domain=2.000002653901591:3.979999999999998] plot(\x,{sqrt(((\x)*((\x)-1.0)*((\x)-2.0))/6.0)});
\draw[line width=0.8pt,smooth,samples=100,domain=6.920000002293365E-6:0.9999961013223213] plot(\x,{0-sqrt(((\x)*((\x)-1.0)*((\x)-2.0))/6.0)});
\draw[line width=0.8pt,smooth,samples=100,domain=2.000002653901591:3.979999999999998] plot(\x,{0-sqrt(((\x)*((\x)-1.0)*((\x)-2.0))/6.0)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```